# Why doesn't this jquery (hover) effect get called when the conditions (removeClass) are met?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, removeclass

Here is the code link http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kzJvl (full code below)

The code should remove all instances of the class `.gigante`

```
$('.gigante').removeClass('gigante');
```

so therefore the hover effect which works on all the items without `.gigante`

```
$civs.hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass("colorise");
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass("colorise");
});
```

should be active on all the elements in the code? should it not?

Yet the second div item still appears to have a remnant of that class or something I don't comprehend

Full code of pen:

JavaScript:

```
var $gigante = $('.gigante');
var $civs = $(".civ-item:not(.gigante)");

// HOVER
$civs.hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass("colorise");
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass("colorise");
});

// REMOVE CLASS
$civs.bind('click', function() {
    $('.gigante').removeClass('gigante');
});
```

CSS:

```
.civ-item{
 float:left;
 background-color: #2D2D2D;
 width: 238px;
 height: 160px;
 border: 1px solid red;
 margin-bottom: 2px;
 }
 .gigante {
    width: 478px;
    height: 600px;
 }
.colorise {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="remove"></div>
     <div id="container" class="clearfix">
        <div class="civ-item"></div>
        <div class="civ-item gigante"></div>
        <div class="civ-item"></div>
        <div class="civ-item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have not understood how event handlers work, they are bound to all elements that match the selector **at the time of binding**, removing the class at a later time does not remove the already bound event handler.

Comment: Always put **all** of the relevant code in the question. In this case, for instance, you weren't showing how `$civs` was filled in, which was vital to understanding the question. Remember links rot, other servers can be unreachable, and people shouldn't have to leave the site to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> should be active on all the elements in the code? should it not?

No, because your `$civs` variable was filled in with the list of elements **before** you removed the class.

You have at least three options:

1. Event delegation - You hook the event on a container of the elements in question (ideally something close to them, but you can use `document` in the worst case), but tell jQuery you only care about the event if it passed through something matching the selector. In your case, you'd hook `mouseenter` for your entering logic and `mouseleave` for your exiting logic.

   ```
   var $gigante = $('.gigante');

   // HOVER
   $(document)
     .on("mouseenter", ".civ-item:not(.gigante)", function() {
       $(this).addClass("colorise");
     })
     .on("mouseleave", ".civ-item:not(.gigante)", function() {
       $(this).removeClass("colorise");
     })
   ;

   // REMOVE CLASS
   $(".civ-item").bind('click', function() {
     $('.gigante').removeClass('gigante');
   });
   ```
2. When you remove the class from the elements, re-query the new set of `$civs` elements an rebind your handler:

   ```
   function civsHandler() {
       $('.gigante').removeClass('gigante');
       $civs = $(".civ-item:not(.gigante)"); // Of course, there aren't any anymore,
                                             // but I'm allowing for the case where
                                             // you only remove some or something
       $civs.unbind('click').bind('click', civsHandler);
   }
   $civs.bind('click', civsHandler);
   ```
3. Bind to all `.civ-item` elements:

   ```
   var $civs = $(".civ-item");
   ```

   ...and check *when the hover occurs* whether it has the `gigante` class:

   ```
   $civs.hover(function() {
     if (!$(this).hasClass("gigante")) {
       $(this).addClass("colorise");
     }
   }, function() {
     if (!$(this).hasClass("gigante")) { // You may or may not want this check
       $(this).removeClass("colorise");
     }
   });
   ```